# Автоматический выбор ориентации печати

Tags: c#, print

```
private void распечататьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // показываем окно настройки печати
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        dlg.Document = printDoc;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(PB_Plan.Image, Point.Empty);
    }
```

Имеется Picturebox (PB_Plan.Image), при нажатии на него правой кнопкой мыши, есть меню "распечатать".

```
PB_Plan.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку печати, делалась проверка ориентации: если документ вертикальный - то книжная, если горизонтальный - то альбомная. Я знаю про свойство landscape, но каким образом изменить код.. у меня что-то ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу методом подбора:(((( Вдруг кому пригодится:

```
private enum PaperOrientation
    {
        Horizontal,
        Vertical
    }

private void РаспечататьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (PB_Plan.Image.Width > PB_Plan.Image.Height)
        {
            paperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Horizontal;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        }
        else
        {
            paperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Vertical;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
        }

        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
        printDoc.Print();
    }

private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if(paperOrientation == PaperOrientation.Horizontal)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(PB_Plan.Image, 10, 10, 1169, 827);
        else
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(PB_Plan.Image, 10, 10, 827, 1169);
    }
```

Если у кого-то есть более умные решения, а они есть... буду рад их тут увидеть.